# Customising layout of new item form

Tags: form, custom, design

I'm implementing a simple suggestion form, with a single field for multiples lines of text.

I've created the list (locked down so that users can only see content they created), and have added the form webpart to the main page of the site.

What I am having trouble with is the layout of the items, shown in the image below:

[image: Layout issues picture]

I'd like to change the dimensions of the text box and the alignment so it can be neater aesthetically.

I've been reading about this issue all morning, and I've tried to edit the XSL directly, and to insert custom CSS via a CEWP, both with no luck.

Grateful for any help anyone can offer.

Cheers

Comment: What's the Sharepoint version 2010 / 2013 ?

Comment: It is Sharepoint Online and I believe it is the 2013 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With additional searching and helped by the blog post that Unnie shared, I found a solution for my particular issue.

I used the "DisplaySize" attribute in the XSL of the webpart to make the entry box wider. I inserted it here:

`<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="My_x0020_idea_x0020_is" DisplaySize="200"`

Answer (score 0):

I will highly recommend this [blog](http://www.markrackley.net/2013/08/29/easy-custom-layouts-for-default-sharepoint-forms/) on custom layouts for SharePoint List forms. I have used it multiple times and it is easy to customize and works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you, that link is very useful. However because I'm putting the form onto a webpart page by inserting it as a new item form via Sharepoint Designer, it is not working. I think the blog relates to changing the default new item form, when I want to edit the layout of the dataformwebpart.